# Convert nested JSON array into flat JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nested JSON array that getting from a mongoDB query that i would like to convert into flat JSON .I am using nested mondo documents, but i would like to show the data in a more readble way.  My JSON has the following structure:

```
[{
     "country": "Country A",
     "regions": [{
            "region": "region A1",
            "cities": [{
                    "city": "city A11"
                },
                {
                 "city": "city A12"
                }
            ]
            },
            {
                "region": "region A2",
                "cities": [{
                        "city": "city A21"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "city A22"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "Country B",
        "regions": [{
                "region": "region B1",
                "cities": [{
                        "city": "city B11"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "city B12"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "region": "region B2",
                "cities": [{
                        "city": "city B21"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "city B22"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to show only the important information and not the structure of the nested array.
How i can modify my data in Javascript on order to achieve the following result.

```
[
  {
    "country": "Country A",
    "region":"Region A1",
    "city": "City A11"
  },
   {
    "country": "Country A",
    "region":"Region A1",
    "city": "City A12"
  },
  -------------
   {
    "country": "Country B",
    "region":"Region B1",
    "city": "City B11"
  },
  -----------
   {
    "country": "Country B",
    "region":"Region B2",
    "city": "City B22"
  }
]
```

What is the simpliest way to acheive this result?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to just loop through and create an array. You can do this with `reduce()`:

```js
let arr = [{"country": "Country A","regions": [{"region": "region A1","cities": [{"city": "city A11"},{"city": "city A12"}]},{"region": "region A2","cities": [{"city": "city A21"},{"city": "city A22"}]}]},{"country": "Country B","regions": [{"region": "region B1","cities": [{"city": "city B11"},{"city": "city B12"}]},{"region": "region B2","cities": [{"city": "city B21"},{"city": "city B22"}]}]}]

let flat = arr.reduce((arr, {country, regions}) => {
    regions.forEach(({region, cities}) => {
        cities.forEach(({city}) => {
            arr.push({country, region, city})
        })
    })
    return arr
}, [])
console.log(flat)
```